# Select first entry list box

Tags: ms-access, vba

Im creating a database an want to select the first record in a list box
after typing into a textfield.

```
Private Sub domSuche_Change()

Dim i As Integer

 For i = 0 To Me!lstSuchergebnis.ListCount - 1

     If Me!lstSuchergebnis.Column(3, i) Like "*" & Me!domSuche.Text & "*" Then

         Me!lstSuchergebnis.Selected(i) = True

     End If

 Next i

End Sub
```

Its working but it selects only the last entry in my list field.

Is there any way to select only the first entry in my list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add an `Exit For` after finding the match

```
Private Sub domSuche_Change()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To Me!lstSuchergebnis.ListCount - 1
        If Me!lstSuchergebnis.Column(3, i) Like "*" & Me!domSuche.Text & "*" Then
            Me!lstSuchergebnis.Selected(i) = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```